# How to write csv inside a loop python

Tags: python, loops, csv

i've done got my outputs for the csv file, but i dont know how to write it into csv file because output result is numpy array

```
def find_mode(np_array) :                                     
        vals,counts = np.unique(np_array, return_counts=True)    
        index = np.argmax(counts)                               
        return(vals[index])                                      



folder = ("C:/Users/ROG FLOW/Desktop/Untuk SIDANG TA/Sudah Aman/testbikincsv/folderdatacitra/*.jpg")
for file in glob.glob(folder):
    a = cv2.imread(file)
    rows = a.shape[0]
    cols = a.shape[1]
    middlex = cols/2                    
    middley = rows/2                     
    middle = [middlex,middley]
    titikawalx = middlex - 10             
    titikawaly = middley - 10
    titikakhirx = middlex + 10           
    titikakhiry = middley + 10
    crop = a[int(titikawaly):int(titikakhiry), int(titikawalx):int(titikakhirx)]
    c = cv2.cvtColor(crop, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    H,S,V = cv2.split(c)
    hsv_split = np.concatenate((H,S,V),axis=1)
    Modus_citra = (find_mode(H))       #how to put this in csv
```

my outputs is modus citra which is array np.uint8, im trying to put it on csv file but im still confused how to write it into csv because the result in loop.

can someone help me how to write it into csv file ? i appreciate every help

Answer (score 1):

Run your loop, and put the data into lists

eg. `mydata = [result1,result2,result3]`

Then use `csv.writerows(mydata)` to write your list into csv rows

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows

Comment: do i put the list inside my loop ?

Comment: and also do i make the csv function outside the loop ?

Comment: if the result is numpy array how do it put it in csv file ?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-a-numpy-array-into-a-csv-file/

Answer (score 0):

You can save your NumPy arrays to CSV files using the savetxt() function. This function takes a filename and array as arguments and saves the array into CSV format. You must also specify the delimiter; this is the character used to separate each variable in the file, most commonly a comma. For example:

`import numpy as np`

`my_array = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])`

`my_file = np.savetxt('randomtext.csv', my_array, delimiter = ',', fmt = '%d')`

`print(my_file)`